# Why ACRA library throws Exception Dialog Even app is not running currently?

Tags: android, performance, acra

I want to add ACRA library to report exception to app developer but This code working fine when app is running currently but it's shows exception even app is closed.

```
import org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode;
import org.acra.annotation.ReportsCrashes;

@ReportsCrashes(formUri = "",
    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.DIALOG,
    mailTo = "xyz@gmail.com",
    resDialogText = R.string.reporttous,
    resDialogOkToast = R.string.OK,
    formKey = "")

public class UILApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    ACRA.init(this);
}
}
```

Any hint or help will be appreciate

Comment: What does the dialog say?

Comment: it's saying what i coded to show. but here problem is even app is closed then still is shows dialog periodically.

Answer (score 2):

ACRA catches crashes that occur within your app and then optionally notifies user and sends you a crash report. It does so by catching uncaught RuntimeExceptions and processing them.

If ACRA has caught an Exception and displayed a notification dialog, it is because your app was running and threw an uncaught exception.

Do not be confused with not visible in foreground and not running. They are not the same thing.